# remove specific line returns ("\n") from file

Tags: python, formatting

I have a file and some lines have a \n in the wrong spot. I am able to find them correctly, but when I try to output my findings to a new file, they still show the \n even though if I print the results, they come out fine. Here is my code so far:

```
f = open("DUP1.txt","r")
w = open("output.txt", "w")
mark = 0

for line in f:
  if mark == 1:
    mark = 0
    w.write(outputline.replace("\n","\t") + line)
  else:
    subp = line.find(".")
    if subp < 8:
      mark = 1
      outputline = line.replace("\n","")
    else:
      w.write(line)
```

the file I am opening looks like:

```
ABC0005    other   info    here
ABC0005.23
other      info    here
ABC0005.46
other      info    here
```

and I am trying to get it to look like:

```
ABC0005    other   info    here
ABC0005.23 other   info    here
ABC0005.46 other   info    here
```

Comment: `w.write(line)` should be `w.write(outputline)` I think.

Comment: no that one is correct because that is if the line does not need any fixing.

Comment: there isn't anything funny going on with hidder characters is there? Like a `\r` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('testdata.txt') as fin, open('testdata.out', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if 0 <= line.find('.') <= 8:
            fout.write(line.rstrip() + '\t' + next(fin))
        else:
            fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
subp = line.find(".")
```

returns `-1` when `"."` is not in `subp`. This messes up your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I can't figure out what is wrong, here is some pretty one-liner:

```
infile = open("test")
outfile = open("out", "w")    
outfile.writelines(s if not i%2 else s.replace("\n", "\t") for i, s in enumerate(infile))
```

Edit: [John Clements's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966220/472416) is better.

Comment: While this does make it a one-liner, it still outputs the same result that I got. =/